# Creating a database containing numbered blocks of TeX-code

Tags: glossaries, datatool, database, content-replication

I want to create a database consisting of numbered blocks of TeX-code. In particular, I want to do sth like `\mycommand{counterName}{Some text}` and save a new entry somewhere, to use the `Some Text` later in another part of the document. The `CounterName` is a counter that I can reffer to get the text inserted in the document:

```
\newcounter{a}
\mycommand{a}{The first line}
\stepcounter{a}
\mycommand{a}{The second line}

.........

print{2}
```

And TeX will produce "The second line".

I am looking for something like `glossaries` package, but with ability to produce not all list at once, but a specific entry so it looks like the command `\print{n}` is simply substituted by the text in command `\mycommand{n}{TEXT}`.

Searching through TeX.SX I found some answers about `datatool` package and `Lua` codes, but haven't found a solution I can apply.

I would really appreciate a brief explanation on how to use `datatool`, `glossaries` or something similar for this stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mentioned `datatool` and `glossaries`, here are some alternatives.

With `datatool`, the simplest method requires defining all entries in incremental order (without using a counter). The row number supplies the indexing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{data}

\newcommand{\addline}[1]{%
  \DTLnewrow{data}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{data}{Text}{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\print}[1]{%
  \DTLgetvalue{\thisval}{data}{#1}{1}%
  \thisval
}

\addline{The first line}
\addline{The second line}

\begin{document}

Line 2: \print{2}.

All lines:

\DTLforeach*{data}{\Text=Text}{\DTLcurrentindex. \Text.\par}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

> Line 2: The second line.
>  All lines:
>   1. The first line.
>   2. The second line.

If you want to define your entries out of order using a counter, this can be done with an additional column:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}

\DTLnewdb{data}

\newcommand{\addline}[2]{%
  \DTLnewrow{data}%
  \dtlexpandnewvalue
  \DTLnewdbentry{data}{Index}{\the\value{#1}}%
  \dtlnoexpandnewvalue
  \DTLnewdbentry{data}{Text}{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\print}[1]{%
  \dtlgetrowindex{\thisrowidx}{data}{1}{#1}%
  \ifx\thisrowidx\dtlnovalue
    Not found!%
  \else
     \DTLgetvalue{\thisval}{data}{\thisrowidx}{2}%
     \thisval
  \fi
}

\newcounter{a}
\setcounter{a}{2}
\addline{a}{The second line}

\setcounter{a}{1}
\addline{a}{The first line}

\begin{document}

Line 2: \print{2}.

All lines:

\DTLforeach*{data}{\theIndex=Index,\Text=Text}{\theIndex. \Text.\par}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

> Line 2: The second line.
>  All lines:
>   2. The second line.
>   1. The first line.

The list is now out of numerical order, but matches the order that the blocks were defined. You can sort them before displaying the list:

```
\DTLsort{Index}{data}
\DTLforeach*{data}{\theIndex=Index,\Text=Text}{\theIndex. \Text.\par}
```

[image: image of document]

> Line 2: The second line.
>  All lines:
>   1. The first line.
>   2. The second line.

Here's a `glossaries` approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\glssetexpandfield{name}

\newcommand{\addline}[2]{%
  \edef\thisidx{\the\value{#1}}%
  \newglossaryentry{\thisidx}{name={\thisidx},description={#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\print}[1]{%
  \glsentrydesc{#1}%
}

\newcounter{a}
\setcounter{a}{2}
\addline{a}{The second line}

\setcounter{a}{1}
\addline{a}{The first line}

\begin{document}

Line 2: \print{2}.

All lines:

\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\printunsrtglossary[style=index]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

Again this lists in order of definition. If you want the list sorted, you can use the following instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automake,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\glssetexpandfield{name}

\newcommand{\addline}[2]{%
  \edef\thisidx{\the\value{#1}}%
  \newglossaryentry{\thisidx}{name={\thisidx},description={#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\print}[1]{%
  \glsentrydesc{#1}\glsadd{#1}%
}

\newcounter{a}
\setcounter{a}{2}
\addline{a}{The second line}

\setcounter{a}{1}
\addline{a}{The first line}

\begin{document}

Line 2: \print{2}.

All lines:

\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\printglossary[style=index,nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

> Line 2: The second line.
>  All lines:
>  2 The second line

This only lists the entry that has been indexed (with `\glsadd`). If you want all the entries to be listed, use `\glsaddall` (after all entries have been defined).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[automake,nopostdot]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\glssetexpandfield{name}

\newcommand{\addline}[2]{%
  \edef\thisidx{\the\value{#1}}%
  \newglossaryentry{\thisidx}{name={\thisidx},description={#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\print}[1]{%
  \glsentrydesc{#1}%
}

\newcounter{a}
\setcounter{a}{2}
\addline{a}{The second line}

\setcounter{a}{1}
\addline{a}{The first line}

\glsaddall

\begin{document}

Line 2: \print{2}.

All lines:

\renewcommand{\glstreenamefmt}[1]{#1}
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\printglossary[style=index,nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

> Line 2: The second line.
>  All lines:
>  1 The first line
>  2 The
>   second line

### Expansion

It's important that the indexing value `\the\value{#1}` is fully expanded before being stored, otherwise it will keep changing as the counter changes value. Both `datatool` and `glossaries` have a way to switch expansion on or off when adding/defining a new entry.

In the case of `datatool`, expansion is switched on using `\dtlexpandnewvalue`. In the case of `glossaries`, expansion is switched on for a particular field using `\glssetexpandfield{`*field-label*`}`.

The code you want to add (in the final argument of `\addline`) may well contain fragile commands, in which case it's important not to expand the value. With `datatool`, the expansion is switched back off again using `\dtlnoexpandnewvalue`. With `glossaries`, the value is being stored in the `description` key and expansion is off by default for that field.

Comment: Thank you! I like the solution with `datatool`. It can serve many requests. And not too difficult, if one opens the `datatool` documentation.

Comment: But I still not fully understant what `\dtlexpandnewvalue` and `\dtlnoexpandnewvalue` do.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann `\dtlexpandnewvalue` switches on expansion so that the new entry is expanded before being added to the database. This is needed otherwise the entry will be `\the\value{a}` which will change as `a` changes. I've then switched off the expansion with `\dtlnoexpandnewvalue` in case the code you want to add contains fragile commands. The `glossaries` version likewise switches on expansion for the `name` field using `\glssetexpandfield{name}`. I'll add a note.

Answer (score 2):

The following is based on the assumption that `\printlistitem` occurs *after* `\addlistitem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{listitem}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addlistitem}{o m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\expandafter\def\csname #1-list\endcsname{#2}}
    {\stepcounter{listitem}%
     \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\expandafter
       \def\noexpand\csname \thelistitem-list\noexpand\endcsname}%
       \x{#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\printlistitem}[1]{%
  \ifcsname #1-list\endcsname
    \csname #1-list\endcsname
  \else
    Item~#1 does not exist.
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\addlistitem{The first line}% 1
\addlistitem[B]{The second line}% C
\addlistitem{The third line}% 2

\printlistitem{2}

\printlistitem{1}

\printlistitem{3}

\printlistitem{B}

\end{document}
```

More modifications can be added, including error checking/handling and modifying it for handling reverse referencing (using a `\label`-`\ref` setup).

---

You may be interested in adding a `\printallitems` to list all the items you've added in the form of a ToC. The following example mimics that by setting each `\addlistitem` as a `\section`. You can do refinements to the presentation as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,tocloft}

\newcounter{listitem}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addlistitem}{o m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\expandafter\def\csname #1-list\endcsname{#2}%
     \addcontentsline{los}{listitem}{\protect\numberline{#1} #2}}
    {\stepcounter{listitem}%
     \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\expandafter
       \def\noexpand\csname \thelistitem-list\noexpand\endcsname}%
       \x{#2}%
     \addcontentsline{los}{listitem}{\protect\numberline{\thelistitem} #2}}%
}

\newcommand{\printlistitem}[1]{%
  \ifcsname #1-list\endcsname
    \csname #1-list\endcsname
  \else
    Item~#1 does not exist.
  \fi
}

\makeatletter
\let\l@listitem\l@section
\newcommand{\printallitems}{{%
  \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\mdseries}% Add more ToC-related tuning here
  \@starttoc{los}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\printallitems

\bigskip

\addlistitem{The first line}% 1
\addlistitem[B]{The second line}% C
\addlistitem{The third line}% 2

\printlistitem{2}

\printlistitem{1}

\printlistitem{3}

\printlistitem{B}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If one would like to access these directly, one could use \renewcommand{\thelistitem}{\Alph{listitem}} or perhaps \Roman.

Comment: Can you please give an explanation on what's going on inside the branch when I do not pass an optional argument?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann: Within `\addlistitem[<tag>]{<stuff>}` we condition on whether `<tag>` is supplied or not. If it is not supplied, we simply create `\<tag>-list` to be `<stuff>`. If it is supplied, we increment the counter (`listitem`) and create `\<\thelistitem>-list` to be `<stuff>`.

Comment: @Werner where exactly are the blocks of text stored? In a database, or as new commands?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann: They're each stored as a new command. The interface makes it seem like there is some external database structure created.

Comment: @Werner Thank you very much! I read `xparse` documentation and quite understood everything. Is there any way to print all the texts I have stored as commands?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann: Yes. One could write each text to a file, and then with a `\printallitems` you read it in like a ToC.

Comment: @Werner can you please give some explanation on how it is done?

Comment: @MichaelFreimann: I'm at work now. Will do later.

Comment: @Werner Surely.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann: See the updated answer.