# Is there an alternative to the exercise package for laying-out examples?

Tags: tables, equations, amsmath, exercises

Using the document class `book` and the `amsmath` package, the `exercise` package, at first, appears to work reasonably well (MWE below).  But, to the average user, it is not supported; for example, there is no example of any substance given in the package details.  One cannot layout sub-examples across the page, and environments like `array`, `equation`, `tabular` etc. are not allowed.  Adapting the headers available is beyond the average user.  Is there a well-supported alternative – perhaps related to the `amsmath` package?

```
%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\documentclass{book}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
%
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} %
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb} %
\usepackage[paperwidth=170mm,paperheight=240mm,textwidth=132mm,driver=none,lmargin=25mm,vmargin=20mm,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} % verbose,showcrop,showframe=inner frame
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop} % pageframe
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed]{exercise}
%
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0mm} %
%
\renewcommand{\subQuestionNB}{\alph{subQuestion}) }

\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\medskip{\textbf{\AnswerName\ %
    \ExerciseHeaderNB}\smallskip}}

\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\textbf{\quad\:\ExerciseName\;\ExerciseHeaderNB\ExerciseHeaderTitle\ExerciseHeaderOrigin} %
  \par\nopagebreak\medskip}

\setlength{\subQuestionIndent}{26pt}

\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter] % Reset counter every chapter
\renewcounter{Answer}[chapter] %
\newcounter{Problem}[chapter] %
%
\def\AnswerName{\par{Answers to questions on section}} %
%
\begin{document}

\chapter{\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont{This header would already be present within the book}}\vspace{-36pt}

\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_01_sec_01},name={Exercises on section},counter={Problem}]
  \Question{What is the symbol for iron?}
  \Question{What is the symbol for hydrogen?}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_01_sec_02},name={Exercises on section},counter={Problem}]
  \Question{What is the symbol for lead?}
  \Question{For hydrogen, state the atomic number}
\end{Exercise}

\chapter{\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont{This header would already be present within the book}}\vspace{-36pt}

\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_02_sec_01},name={Exercises on section},counter={Problem}]
  \Question{What is the symbol for copper?}
  \Question{What is the form of oxygen?}
\end{Exercise}

\begin{Exercise}[label={chap_02_sec_02},name={Exercises on section},counter={Problem}]
  \Question{What is the symbol for zinc?}
  \Question{What is the form of zinc}
\end{Exercise}
%
% There are four sets of answers that follow
% The first two sets belong to chapter 1, the second two sets to chapter 2
%
% I want a chapter 1 header to go here
%
  \begin{Answer}[ref={chap_01_sec_01}]
    \Question{Fe=iron}     
  \Question{H} 
  \end{Answer}

  \begin{Answer}[ref={chap_01_sec_02}]
  \Question{Pb=lead}
    \Question{1}
  \end{Answer}

% and a chapter 2 header to go here

  \begin{Answer}[ref={chap_02_sec_01}]
    \Question{Cu=copper}     
  \Question{oxygen is a gas} 
  \end{Answer}

  \begin{Answer}[ref={chap_02_sec_02}]
  \Question{Zn=zinc}
    \Question{zinc is a metal}
  \end{Answer}

\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at `exsheets`?

Comment: CTAN lists [several packages for exams](http://ctan.org/topic/exam) and [several packages for exercises](http://ctan.org/topic/exercise). BTW: [There will be a successor of `exsheets`.](http://www.mychemistry.eu/2017/02/improving-exsheets/)

Comment: @Schweinebacke Would you put it as an answer? Thx

Comment: @jjdb This would be a ridiculous answer.

Comment: @Schweinebacke how do we close the question then? Would you then flag it as too broad maybe? I'd prefer an answer…

Comment: @jjdb The OP has added an example to the question. So there can still be answers showing how to use one of the alternatives for it. Please don't be so quick with close requests.

Comment: `\chapter{\fontsize{11}{12}\selectfont{This header would already be present within the book}}\vspace{-36pt}` – really? o.O

Comment: clemens - not within (inside) the group of answers.  But besides that, there are multiple issues.

Comment: the question isn't very clear, you state that `equation` can not be used for example, but I just added an `equation` and an `align` to a question and it worked without error, similarly you say `array` can not be used but `array` is math mode and as ling as you start math mode then any math commands and environments should work.

Comment: @keith77777 I don't understand your reply… What I meant earlier is that you *really* should only be writing “`\chapter{This header would already be present within the book}`” in the document. The layout of the chapter title can be changed once in the preamble (eg with the help of `titlesec`). Doing it manually each time you call `\chapter` is both tedious and error-prone!

Comment: @Clemens  I agree that \chapter should only be called within the normal run of the book - say 6 times.  My questions are placed in the text file immediately after each chapter.  But when the 6 sets of answers are brought together using \shipoutAnswer, each one of the 6 sets should ideally have one chapter reference - and they do not.

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks for performing that check; I will retrace my steps to see what I did wrongly.

Comment: @keith77777 Clemens point is that you should never have font selection commands in the argument to `\chapter`

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes, but a MWE is not part of a book; I had to simulate it being a book, hence include some kind of header.

Comment: @keith77777 I don't understand that comment, sorry. I think editing the question is more likely to get answers than the bounty. The question title asks if alternative packages exist which seems to be covered by the first couple of comments. Then you have a block of code with an example but no actual question about that code, and then you have a statement about things like `array` and `tabular` not being allowed in the class which doesn't seem correct. What do you want as an answer, an alternative package as implied by the title or a change to the supplied code to make it do something else?

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes, it has become a muddle and I apologise for my mistakes regarding $mathmode$.  What I wanted was a usable package to place exercises in a book.  The most likely answer was \exercise, and I think all the facilities I need are now resolved - except one - how to place, say, 3 short subQuestions across the page as distinct from serially down the page.

Comment: Why are you cropping with an assumed pre-crop area larger than the paper size?

Comment: Have a look at my question, where a `datatool` as well as `glossaries` solution is presented. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366274/creating-a-database-containing-numbered-blocks-of-tex-code

Comment: @Michael Freimann - Thanks, but I can't change course now.